# Is there a way to autostart progress bar in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a progressbar which is rendered based on a dropDownMenu value. After loading the progressbar, I need to start it somehow automatically or any workaround?

```
<p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{myBean.progress}"
                                           labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated" global="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start progress bar:

PF('pbAjax').start();

Comment: My bad, I was not clear in the question. I dont have any button clicks to start the progress bar, then where to write this PF('pbAjax').start();to start the progress bar?

Comment: Use onchange attribute or ajax change event in primefaces dropdown component

Answer (score -1):

You'd like to show the progressBar when user changes item? I guess you use a Primefaces dropdown. If so, add the `onChange` attribute on your dropdown and start the progress bar by `PF('pbAjax').start();`